# Distribution of prime ideals by norm

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was wondering if there exist results in arithmetic statistics which count the number of prime ideals of bounded degree in a given number field, for instance a (real or imaginary) quadratic number field? Concretly, I wonder if we have asymptotics of
$$\{\mathfrak{p}\in Spec(\mathcal{O}_K)\mid Nm(\mathfrak{p})\leq L\}$$
as $L\rightarrow \infty$? All the articles I've found give asymptotics for the number of number fields of boundd discriminant.

Comment: Yes, look for the prime ideal theorem.

Comment: This is the prime number theorem for $\zeta_K(s)$, the proof is the same as the one for $\zeta(s)$